# Access denied to a file on FAT file system

Tags: windows-7, windows, sd-card, fat32

I just got a new phone which is supplied with a 2 GB SD card. I bought a bigger card to replace it and I want to copy the preloaded data to the new card.

The default card's filesystem is FAT and I've formatted the new card with FAT32.
So far so good.

When I'm trying to copy the data from the default card, I receive an `access denied` error on some of the files, the system won't allow me to read them.

How can I unlock these files? As this is a FAT file system, taking ownership in Windows 7 doesn't have any effect. I tried creating an image and writing the image but that makes the partition only 2 GB big - and doesn't really fix the problem of me being unable to copy (e.g. backup) the files.

Comment: Are you able to identify the files that you cannot copy?

Comment: @Karan, Identify how? They are different types, some of them are images, some mp3 files, some special files of the symbian OS.

Comment: The phone came with a 2GB SD card, and you bought a bigger one?  Can you confirm that the first card was a 2 GB SDHC card?  The reason I ask is, if you bought a larger card, it would HAVE to be an SDHC card (SD cards maxed out at 2GB).  Can I ask for the model of the phone so that we can confirm that it works with SDHC cards?  Just want to get any hardware incompatibility out of the way.

Comment: Yes, what I wanted to know was whether it was just having problems with some system files, or even normal user files. BTW, what sort of card reader are you using to access both cards? Can you try another one?

Comment: @Everett: Regarding hardware incompatibility, as far as I can see the problem is with transferring the files from the old card to the new one via a Windows machine. Phone incompatibility issues are altogether separate.

Comment: Somehow I got that the phone was involved in the process the first time I read the question.  Sorry about the red herring folks.

Comment: Here's a crazy thought.  Since you've tried the .iso (creating an image) approach, why not mount the .iso in Windows and copy it out of the image to the new card?  Directions for this process:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/

Comment: @Everett, Ok, to clarify - I can access both of the cards without a problem with a separate reader (I use my Garmin GPS for work with microSD cards). The problems I'm having are only with *some* files on the original card - I can see them ok but I can't open/copy them. The phone is a Nokia C2-03 (Symbian 40 Series).

Comment: if you CD to the card in cmd.exe or powershell, and run the 'attrib' command, do any of the files have attributes like S or R?

Comment: @FrankThomas, they have Read-only and Archive attributes. I'm unable to change any of the attributes (`access denied`).

Comment: @Everett, it was a bit more complicated since I was only able to create an `img` image but unable to mount it. But with the help of some shareware I was able to extract the data out of it and copy it to the card. If you make your 'crazy thought' into an answer, I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tried the .iso (creating an image) approach, why not mount the .iso in Windows and copy it out of the image to the new card? Directions for this process: howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/…

Answer (score 0):

Can you run chkdsk on the card, or a similar tool, to see if the operating system is rejecting reads from them because of corruption?

Answer (score 0):

If you just tried to mass copy everything on it, your phone has likely placed some files on it that are locked for it's use only, and you wouldn't want them anyway.

Unless you skip those that are denied and then you can pinpoint an actual file as having be one of yours...

Comment: Can you expand upon this? I suspect this is an MTP issue—the computer isn't accessing the device as regular block storage.